# Why raising numpy array in a power larger than 9 returns wrong results?

Tags: numpy

I don't understand why raising in powers larger than 9 doesn't work for me. Seems simple: I am just trying to raise 10, for example, in the power of 10, but for whatever reason numpy fails. What could be the problem?

```
import numpy as np
number = 10
arr = [number]

print(np.power(np.array(arr),number)) # [1410065408]
print([n**number for n in arr]) # [10000000000]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Why*** raising `numpy` array in a power larger than 9 returns wrong results ?

Because of an implicit ( assumed from type-inference ) **`dtype`**, that was used upon the `np.array` instantiation plus the overflow side-effects:

```
>>> np.power( np.array( arr, dtype = np.int64 ), 10 )
array([10000000000], dtype=int64)

>>> np.power( np.array( arr, dtype = np.int32 ), 10 )
array([-2147483648])

>>> np.power( np.array( arr, dtype = np.int   ), 10 )
array([-2147483648])

>>> np.power( np.array( arr                   ), 10 )
array([-2147483648])

>>> pass;     np.array( arr ).dtype
dtype('int32')
```

Comment: And what would be a solution to this?

Comment: Obviously, a proper, type-safe `numpy.array` instantiation, set **as printed above** -- using **`np.array( arr, dtype = np.int64 )`**

Comment: With int64 (which on my system is somehow default) it overflows with 20th power

Comment: Huh, it does overflow on 19th power and 20th power even with type being long.

Comment: Do not get surprised, these are elementary facts. If you seek an arbitrary precision number representation, the `np.array( ..., dtype = ... )` may be possible for storing values. Whereas this is yet not sufficient for also **doing** all the arbitrary precision mathematic operations, as one needs also to go into using proper tools for such number representation ( this goes way beyond the scope of this post ). One may find more detailed posts on arbitrary precision operations, either here, on StackOveflow or elsewhere, altogether with examples going way beyond 1E+4 decimal places, if interested.

Comment: @user366197 The reason why I'm confused is that the Python numbers (`long` datatype) IS arbitrary integral numbers. If I set `tenth = 10000000000` and try to compute `tenth ** 10`, it gives me what is expected: 1 followed by 100 zeros. `type(tenth ** 10)` gives `<type 'long'>`, which is definitely a language built in. `tenth ** 1000` also works just fine.